# Graphics dont appear

Tags: java

Whatever I do, I can not display rectangle/line/oval on the screen. I checked other sources where they paint graphics, but when I even execute those codes, I don't get any graphics displayed on the windows. Below is the example from the text book.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PlotGraph
{
   public static void main (String [] args) {
    JFrame win;
    Container contentPane;
    Graphics g;

    win = new JFrame("testing");
    win.setSize(300,200);
    win.setLocation(100,100);
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setVisible(true);

    contentPane = win.getContentPane();
    g = contentPane.getGraphics();

    g.drawRect(10, 30, 50, 50); 

   }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what book is this?

Comment: OOP with Java by Thomas WU, 5th edition. page 257

Comment: I also saw this video on graphics but I was getting the same problem of graphics not appearing but in the video it does for the person explaining it - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l5-5PMUc5Y&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how graphics work in Swing.

You need to add a *component* to your frame, not just draw on it. You never want to draw directly on the frame. The reason why it's not doing anything is because your drawing code is being overridden.

If you want your component to have custom drawing code, make a subclass of `JComponent` and override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. An example of how you *should* do this is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PlotGraph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame win;

        win = new JFrame("testing");
        win.setSize(300, 200);
        win.setLocation(100, 100);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setContentPane(new MyComponent());
    }

}

class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(10, 30, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I would *highly* encourage you to check out the [Java GUI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) online.

Comment: +1 for linking to the Swing tutorial. -1 for adding the component after the frame is visible and not executing the code on the EDT.

Comment: WChargin - I have a question. It works but how does paintComponent method gets invoked? Like what object is calling it.. All I see we create a new object of the MyComponent class which has that one void methods. What if I had more than one methods?

Comment: Painting is determined/scheduled by the repaint manager. Rock out [Psinting in AWT & Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a more detailed description

Answer (score 3):

Ouch. You should change your text book then. First of all, all the accesses to Swing components must be done in the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Second, you should not get the graphics of a component and paint on it. Instead, you should extend a JComponent or JPanel, override its `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, and paint using the Graphics object passed as argument (and which is in fact a `Graphics2D` instance).